# PieChart / Listener event of a google fusion table

Tags: jquery, google-fusion-tables, google-visualization

I have a fusion table with two columns ('TOTAL_ROOF' & 'POTENTIAL_'). 'POTENTIAL_' is a subset of 'TOTAL_ROOF'.

Right now I am:

1) Showing formated row data determined by the users 'click'

2) trying to draw a PieChart  i.e.: drawVisualization.PieChart(e.row['TOTAL_ROOF', "POTENTIAL_'].value);

I've gotten #1 to work... However, for #2 I am a bit lost on what to do...all the examples I see show the PieChart already being created BEFORE the user has clicked anything.

Is there a way to create the PieChart after the click? Leaving the space blank until (like it is for #1)?

Also I don't see how to call it in a  into my text-box (ex: http://jsfiddle.net/fG5a5/1/).

Here is my code so far:

load libraries:

```
google.load('maps', '3.5', {other_params:'sensor=false'});
google.load('jquery', '1.6.0');
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:["corechart"]});
google.load('jqueryui', '1.8.12');
```

js

```
var tableid = 1DGswslbC5ijqWHPJvOH1NH7vltkZIPURJun_L5I;
var location_column = 'geometry'

  function drawVisualization() {
    google.visualization.drawChart({
    "chartType": "PieChart"

    })};
      // Draw Visualization of WHAT (the event listener has not been triggered??)

      function initialize() {

      google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
      $("#roof-panel-area").html(
  '<p><strong>Total Roof Area (sqft)</strong>: ' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + 
      Math.round(e.row['TOTAL_ROOF'].value) + 
  '<br><strong> Potential Roof Area (sqft)</strong>:' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' 
       +  Math.round(e.row['POTENTIAL_'].value) + 
  '<br><strong> Pitched or Flat Roof (?)</strong>:'+ '&nbsp;&nbsp;' +     
       e.row['PITCHED_OR'].value + 
  '<br><strong> # of Panels per Roof Area :</strong>' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + 
       Math.round(e.row['NUMBER_OF_'].value) + '</p>');
   });

   // Click Listener on layer using jquery  , searches for fields related to 
 // roof/panel, 

   google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
  drawVisualization.PieChart(e.row['TOTAL_ROOF','POTENTIAL_'].value);
        });
   // Click Listener - updates graph        

    layer.setMap(map);
 }
```

html:

```
<div id="sidebarItem">
    <br>
    <h1> Hatfield Solar Map</h1>
    <!---Create a text box input for the user to enter the street address-->
    Address: <input type="text" id="inputTextAddress" style=" width:200px" title="Address to Geocode" />
    <!--Create a button input for the user to click to geocode the address-->
    <input type="button" onclick="codeAddress()" id="inputButtonGeocode" style="width:200px" title="Click to Find Address" value="Click to Find Address" />
    <h3>Select a building outline or search for an address to identify buildings that you'd like to select.</h3>
    <!---Content from Click-->
    <hr/>
    <div id="sidebar-content-area" style="padding:5px;">
        <div id="intro" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px; display: none;">
            <p><i>Buildings are symbolized according to roof size, and the possibility of increased panel placement.</i><p>
        </div>
    <div id="overview" style:"">
        <h3>Building Overview:</h3>
    <p id ="roof-panel-area"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok -- got it...

js Function 1:

```
function drawVisualization(e) {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Area', 'Potential', 'Total'],
          ['Building',  Math.round(e.row['POTENTIAL_'].value), Math.round(e.row['TOTAL_ROOF'].value)],
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    };
```

js function 2:

```
             google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
         $("#roof-panel-area").html(
         '<p><strong>Total Roof Area (sqft)</strong>: ' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + Math.round(e.row['TOTAL_ROOF'].value) + 
         '<br><strong> Potential Roof Area (sqft)</strong>:' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + Math.round(e.row['POTENTIAL_'].value) + 
         '<br><strong> Pitched or Flat Roof (?)</strong>:'+ '&nbsp;&nbsp;' +  e.row['PITCHED_OR'].value + 
         '<br><strong> # of Panels per Roof Area :</strong>' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + Math.round(e.row['NUMBER_OF_'].value) +
         '</p>');
         drawVisualization(e);
        });

    layer.setMap(map);

}
```

html

```
        <div id="overview" style:"">
        <h3>Building Overview:</h3>
    <p id ="roof-panel-area"></p>
    <div id = "visualization_div" style="align: center; width: 230px; height: 260px;"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to do with this line:

```
...
drawVisualization.PieChart(e.row['TOTAL_ROOF','POTENTIAL_'].value);
```

maybe you should just make a function like:

```
....
var whateverClicked = function(){
    //do something;
};
```

and append it to the listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', whateverClicked);
```